# What is the purpose of $ in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm taking an XML class online and I'm not entirely sure what the "$" is used for.

Specifically, here is a block from the text book..

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('agentID', $aID)" />
```

The dollar sign in front of aID is where I am confused. Why does it need to be there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is actually an XPath rule -- thus it can be used in any XPath expression inside XSLT code.

**The `$` character is used as the first character in a variable (or parameter) reference within an XPath expression**.

Thus:

```
$person
```

means: the xsl variable or parameter named `person`.

If we use just:

```
person
```

**this means something completely different**: all children of the context node that are named `person`

Forgetting the `$` before the variable name in a variable reference is one of the most frequent mistakes comited by XSLT programmers.

**It is a good practice to use such names for variables or parameters, that visually indicate that the named object is a variable/parameter**.

For example, I always prefix the name of a variable with `v` and the name of the parameter with `p`:

```
$vPerson

$pTable
```

Comment: @Cluckles, You are welcome -- see my updated answer for more information. Also, please, consider *accepting* this answer.